# How to read JSON file of objects into a list in Java with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
 public class Town {    

    private Person p;

    private String hello;
    private long number;
}

public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private double legs;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I am trying to write the Town class to JSON using the below code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
 writer.writeValue(out, townobj);
```

Which produces Json like this.

```
{
  "p" : {
    "firstName" : "John",
    "amount" : 6860.0,
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },
  "hello" : "qwiejiowcqnio",
  "number" : 1380.0
}

{
  "p" : {
    "firstName" : "Sam",
    "amount" : 623460.0,
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },
  "hello" : "qwiej2342io",
  "number" : 1330.0
}
```

How do I read such an output produced from nested objects into Java with jackson?

Comment: So you know how to use `mapper.writer()`. Isn't it obvious, when looking at javadoc of [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), that the opposite operation would use `mapper.reader()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read two objects as a list into Java, you need to write them as a list as well:

```
List<Town> towns = new ArrayList<>();
towns.add(townobj);
towns.add(anotherTownobj);

writer.writeValue(out, towns);
```

When you read that back it becomes a List again.

The output you've shown in your question as not a valid single json file. But using the above method will get you a valid single json file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "p" : {
        "firstName" : "John",
        "amount" : 6860.0,
        "lastName" : "Smith"
      },
      "hello" : "qwiejiowcqnio",
      "number" : 1380.0
    },
    {
      "p" : {
        "firstName" : "Sam",
        "amount" : 623460.0,
        "lastName" : "Smith"
      },
      "hello" : "qwiej2342io",
      "number" : 1330.0
    }
]
```

Comment: Thankyou for this answer. If I have an existing JSON file like above, how can I append more objects to the array in the file?